# Is 「インターネットはカタツムリのように速い。」a strange expression?

Tags: expressions

If I complain to the Internet Service Provider and say a sarcasm as follows

> インターネットはカタツムリのように速い。

Is it a strange expression? Must it be rephrased directly as follows?

> インターネットはカタツムリのように遅い。

Is the former expression (with a sarcasm) used among  Japanese?

How about インターネットはカタツムリのような速さだ。?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

インターネットはカタツムリのように速い may be understood by some people as a tricky sarcastic expression, but usually you should say one of the followings:

- インターネットはカタツムリのように遅い。
- インターネットはカタツムリ並【なみ】に遅い。
- インターネットはカタツムリのような｛遅さ／速さ／速度｝だ。
- インターネットはカタツムリ並の｛遅さ／速さ／速度｝だ。

Note that these refer to a general characteristic of the internet because of the use of は. If you want to report a temporary status of your internet connection, you must use が (e.g., なんだかインターネットが遅いな).